Eclipse Content Assist Pallet Opening Else Where on Screen
I am having an issue with eclipse content assist. It is opening suggestion box at different location on screen as shown in screenshot. Also another issue with this eclipse is it does not autocomplete sysout template. It gives suggestions instead of adding System.out.println(); statement. I am using ubuntu 22.04 with x11 and not wayland. Weird things are happening in eclipse.


Not sure about the popup's location, but you didn't type "sysout" before invoking Content Assist, so I wouldn't expect that template to show up.

i have a template for sout too. And it just shows suggestions instead of printing System.out.println();
